# sane network scanner - Device busy

Tags: 20.04, sane

Sane will detect the Network Scanner and always gives this message: `Device busy`.

I have tried to restart both the machine and the scanner.

```
$ scanimage
Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.
scanimage: open of device escl:https://172.18.14.250:443 failed: Device busy
```

```
$ scanimage -L
device `escl:https://172.18.14.250:443' is a ESCL RICOH SP 377SFNwX (cf3d23) SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://172.18.14.250:631' is a ESCL RICOH SP 377SFNwX (cf3d23) flatbed scanner
```

Ubuntu 20.04

Installed the packages with:
`sudo apt install sane libsane libsane-common libsane-hpaio`

What might be wrong?

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same problem with my HP MFP M28W over wifi,